# Computing transition probability of squared random variable in a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Suppose we have the following transition diagram for a homogeneous Markov chain $(Z_n)_{n \geq 0}$:

[image]

Now consider the sequence of random variables $(Z_n^2)_{n \geq 0}$.

How would I go about computing $\mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0|Z_1^2 = 1)$?

If $Z_1^2 = 1$, then either $Z_1 = 1$ or $Z_1 = -1$, one having transition probability $1$ and the other having transition probability $\frac{1}{2}$, to $0$. I'm not sure how to combine these two facts to calculate what $\mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0|Z_1^2 = 1)$ is, since it is not clear whether to start at $1$ or $-1$.

Also, I tried using the Law of Total Probability of conditional probabilities, but it would require computing quantities like $\mathbb{P}(Z_1 = 1|Z_1^2 = 1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Z_1 = -1|Z_1^2 = 1)$.

Comment: question is if $Z_1^2 = 1$ what can we say about these $P(Z_1 = 1 | Z_1^2=1)$, $P(Z_1 = -1| Z_1^2=1)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_n=Z_n^2$

Then $$\begin{align}P(Y_2 = y | Y_1 = 1)&= \frac{P(Y_2 = y , Y_1 = 1)}{P(Y_1 = 1)}\\
&=\frac{P(Y_2 = y \cap ( Z_1 = 1 \cup Z_1=-1))}{P( Z_1 = 1 \cup Z_1=-1))}\\
&=\frac{P(Y_2 = y | Z_1 = 1) P(Z_1 = 1) + P(Y_2 = y | Z_1 = -1) P(Z_1 = -1)}{P(Z_1 = 1)+P(Z_1 = -1)}
\end{align}$$

Hence the $Y-$states transition probabilities alone are not enough.

Either you know the initial $Z-$states probabilities, and plug that into the formula above. Or either you compute the stationary $Z-$states probabilities (with that you get the $Y-$states probabilities) and with that you can compute the (steady) $Y-$states transition probabilities.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder how it differs from the computation of $\mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0|Z_1^1 = 1, Z_0^2 = 0)$. We have that $\mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0|Z_1^1 = 1, Z_0^2 = 0)\mathbb{P}(Z_1^1 = 1|Z_0^2 = 0) = \mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0,Z_1^1 = 1|Z_0^2 = 0)$. From the transition diagram, $\mathbb{P}(Z_1^1 = 1|Z_0^2 = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $\mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0,Z_1^1 = 1|Z_0^2 = 0) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{8}$. So $\mathbb{P}(Z_2^2 = 0|Z_1^1 = 1, Z_0^2 = 0) = \frac{6}{8} = \frac{3}{4}$. So we didn't have to know what the initial state probabilities were.